# Pandas how to create unique 4 character string from longer string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a a pandas dataframe with strings.  I would like to shorten them so I have decided to remove the vowels.  Then my next step is to take the first four characters of the string but I am running into collisions.  Is there a smarter way to do this so that I can try not to have repeatable strings but also keep to 4 character strings?

```
import pandas as pd
import re

d = {'test': ['gregorypolanco','franciscoliriano','chrisarcher', 'franciscolindor']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def remove_vowels(r):
    result = re.sub(r'[AEIOU]', '', r, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    return result

no_vowel = pd.DataFrame(df['test'].apply(remove_vowels))

no_vowel['test'].str[0:4]
```

Output:

```
0    grgr
1    frnc
2    chrs
3    frnc
Name: test, dtype: object
```

From the above you can see that 'franciscoliriano' and 'franciscolindor' are the same when shortened.

Comment: if what you care about is uniqueness, python's `hash` builtin is the way to go.

Comment: So you want a hash of only constenants only 4 characters long. That's only 21^4 = 194,481 unqiue combinations, and some letters (such as t and s are going to be much more common). You are bound to have collisions with such small entropy.

Comment: Why not run something like `.map(lambda x: ''.join(random.sample(x, 4)))` on the column after removing vowels? Can't guarantee avoiding collisions but at least it is randomised so the chances are low.

Comment: Yeah the reason for doing this is I have a bunch of these and they must be human readable so that someone that looks may be able to interpret it without unhashing

Comment: let me try it @cs95

Comment: @sectechguy - I have a similar thing I am working on, how did this pan out for you? (Exactly one year to the day later lol)